# Gear vr galaxy s6 edge plus

Tags: samsung

I have a Samsung Galaxy s6 edge plus from Verizon but I'm currently using it on page plus unlimited plan I recently bought a Samsung gear vr oculus headset and after I place the phone in it nothing happens what can I do thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is the phone's software up to date? You need to have the oculus/gear vr system processes running for the phone to register gear vr.